# acceleration word problem using integration

Tags: calculus, integration

If the acceleration $a$ (in $\mathrm m/\mathrm s^2$) of an object is $a = (3t-8)^{-2}$, find the velocity at $t= 6\mathrm s$ if the initial velocity is $2 \mathrm m/\mathrm s$.

I know I have to find the integral but the $-2$ is throwing me off and I keep getting a negative number as my answer.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please show your work so far. :)

Comment: Note that $a$ should actually be written $a=(3t-8\mathrm s)^{-2}\mathrm m$. Always incorporate the units you're using into the equation when appropriate rather than letting things with dimensions look dimensionless. This will help you catch many errors early.

Comment: @dfeuer: The OP correctly stated the units of $a$ as "m/sec$^2$" (not meters, as you've suggested).  This was in the original post, although an Edit has touched up the formatting.

Comment: @hardmath: the $m$ at the end of dfeuer's formula is not a statement of the units of the quantity, but rather a constant whose units are metres.

Comment: @hardmath, the point is that $3t-8$ doesn't make sense. $3t$ has units (seconds) while $8$ does not. The expression I gave has dimensions of $\mathrm m/\mathrm s^2$. More generally, it is good practice to put all units where they belong throughout the calculation, rather than throwing them away leaving just numbers and then throwing them back in at the end.

Comment: @dfeuer: I take your point.  Checking the units can help to detect errors.  For those who have mastered the math, it can be useful to try keeping all the units "throughout the calculation", but here the physical interpretation seems to be an artifice.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

The function you need to integrate is $$(3t - 8\mathrm s)^{-2}\mathrm m = \dfrac{1\mathrm m}{(3t - 8\mathrm s)^2}$$  If you don't immediately see how we can apply the power rule in integration, you can use $u$-substitution?

Let $u = 3t - 8\mathrm s\implies du = 3\,dt \iff \frac 13 du = dt.\;$ Then your integrand becomes $$\dfrac {1\mathrm m}3 u^{-2}\,du = \dfrac {1\mathrm m}{3u^2}\,du.$$

Do you recognize how to integrate, now?

You'll need to use the power rule: $$\int ax^n \,dx \quad = \quad a \int x^n\, dx \quad = \quad \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} + C, \quad\text{ except when }\;n = -1$$

Now, simply answer the questions: What are your bounds $a, \;b\,$ of integration $\displaystyle \left(\int_{t = a}^{t = b}\right)$ when integrating with respect to $t$?

And so the bounds for integrating with respect to $u$ are given by $u = 3t - 8\mathrm s$: Now, you're set to put it all together and evaluate:

$$\frac 13 \int_{u = 3a - 8\mathrm s}^{u = 3b - 8\mathrm s} \frac {1\mathrm m}{u^2}\,du$$

Answer (score 1):

To find the velocity, you have to find the integral of the acceleration function.

$v(t)=\int a(t) dt=\int (3t-8)^{-2} dt=-\frac{1}{3(3t-8)}+C$

We know that $v(0) = 2$, and so we know that $C$ will equal:

$2=\frac{1}{24}+C; C=\frac{47}{24}$

$v(t)$ is then:

$v(t) = -\frac{1}{3(3t-8)}+\frac{47}{24}$

We want $v(6)$ so just plug 6 in for t and you will get:

$v(6)=1.925 \frac{m}{s}$

Answer (score 1):

There's something fishy in the set-up of the problem.  The expression for acceleration,

$$a(t) = {1\over(3t-8)^2}$$

goes to infinity at $t=8/3$, which is between $t=0$ and $t=6$.  Any attempt to integrate it across the singularity at $8/3$ is destined to fail.

Comment: Not only does $a(t)$ become infinite within the finite interval of time proposed, performing the integration once for velocity and again for position shows that $v(t)$ and $x(t)$ also become infinite in this interval.  That the velocity is negative on the other side of this singularity (the point that puzzled the OP) corresponds to a particle "coming back" from infinity.  A case of formal methods applying to give a physically dubious result.